# FancyBox iframe returns parent.$ as undefined (using WordPress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, fancybox, undefined

I'm trying to close [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) from within the iframe, but `parent.$` is always `undefined`.
This is my iframe JavaScript:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' 
  src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'>
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     (function($) {
         $.fn.closeFancyBox = function() {
             $(this).click(function() {
                 parent.$.fancybox.close();
             });
         };
      })(jQuery);
      $('#cancel').closeFancyBox();
      });
 });
 </script>
```

Replacing `parent.$.fancybox.close();` with `alert('clicked');` works just fine. I don't understand why `parent.$` is `undefined` when the iframe is in the same domain.

I'm using WordPress 2.9.1, with the FancyBox for Wordpress plugin.

- main page: `//server.local/web/test/index.php`
- iframe page: `//server.local/web/test/wp-content/plugins/wp-test/test.htm`

The first of these urls is the main page, the second is the iframe page; `server.local` is my home test server.

Any ideas? I can pastebin the entire source if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent quite a few hours trying to debug this and got nowhere. **So I switched out the 'FancyBox for WordPress' plugin with the latest version of FancyBox, and it was fixed.** Really should have tried that earlier.

After having spent some time with WordPress and its various plugins, I'd recommend calling things manually rather relying on plugins. It just adds another layer of complexity that, if you know what you're doing, doesn't need to be there.

Thanks to Doug for pointing out the appropriate syntax for iframe to parent window jQuery in WordPress.

Answer (score 7):

It is undefined because WordPress runs jQuery in [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) mode. Use this instead:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

`noConflict` mode means `$` does not equal jQuery. You have to explicitly use `jQuery` to access what you normally can access with `$`.

Comment: Sorry, should have said that I am aware of this; the js I included was a snippet. I've edited my question to reflect this--passing $ means I don't have to use 'jQuery'.

Comment: @Aleksandr Passing `$` in an `iframe` won't affect the parent page at all. In fact, you are including a completely separate instance of jQuery in the `iframe`. If you notice what you wrote, you pass `$`, but reference `parent.$`. It is as if you have `var a = 1; alert(obj.a);` You wouldn't expect the two items to refer to the same value unless there was an assignment somewhere in the code.

Comment: You're right, that makes sense. However, using the following code: `jQuery('#cancel').click(function(){ parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); });`
I still get `undefined` errors in Firebug: `parent.jQuery.fancybox is undefined`. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Thanks for your help so far! I'm still very much new to JavaScript and coding in general.

Comment: @Aleksandr I am at work right now, but I will try a solution when I get a chance and update my answer with the results.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is not related to wordpress, but one for fancybox in general.

in the iframe, if you have included the main jquery script(jquery-1.5.2.min.js), then it will conflict with the one on the main page, and  **parent.$.fancybox** will not work in this case.

other jquery related stuff (like for eg: the tabs) will work inside the iframe.
hence, it wont occur to a novice programmer that the second jquery script inside the iframe is the villain.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this:

window.top.window.$.fancybox.close();

Got type error before.

Answer (score 3):

Any variations of parent.fancybox.close() didn't work for me, must be some lib conflict.

here is my working workaround for latest fancybox, you should use css display property instead of .hide() method as in that case fancybox will not open again.

```
parent.jQuery('#fancybox-overlay').css('display', 'none');
parent.jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ;)

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();" >
```

Thanks for this post, it actually guided me a little... I feel bad because it took me a only a few minutes and I KNOW how frustrating Fancybox for Wordpress is!!

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions worked for me. I had to work around it using the following code.
The latest version may be supporting the parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); approach, but the older versions do not work with that.

For existing sites with older versions of the plugins/Jquery, try this

```
function close_window()
{
 $("#fancy_outer",window.parent.document).hide();
 $("#fancy_overlay",window.parent.document).hide();
 //window.top.window.$.fancybox.close(); this also does not work :(
}
```

you could declare and use the function close_window within the Iframe content.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and noticed that I am not using the

```
type:'iframe'
```

When calling the fancybox,
it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

HI,
Anyone who is having trouble closing a Fancy Box iFrame using a manual install of Fancy Box in Wordpress 3.0:

Use this link in your iframe:

```
<a href="#" onClick="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" title="Close window">close fancybox</a>
```

It works :)