# How to close fancybox from child window?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

parent link:

```
<a href="feedback.php" id="feed">Provide your feedback here</a>
```

jQuery code to initiate fancybox is...

```
$("#feed").fancybox();
```

codes in feedback.php...

```
      <html>
        <head>
<script language="javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feed_submit").click(function(){
    //Name is alerted
    alert($("#name").val());

    //code to close fancy box(Not working)
    $.fancybox.close();

    });
    });
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" name="feedback" id="feedback" action="">
                <div>
                    <label>name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>feedback</label>
                    <input type="text" name="content" id="content"/>
                </div>
        <div><input type="button" name="feed_submit" id="submit" value="submit"></div>
    </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Once submit button is clicked i need to close fancy box in this page itself with jquery**

i have tried using

```
$.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

But this doesn't work for me. If there is any option to close inside this ajax form please let  me know.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: @karim79 I think that's all the relevant code.

Comment: works for me $.fancybox.close(); thnx, I was searching for this :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code *should* work, and has worked for many people

```
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

However, I have also seen, for instance [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227096/fancybox-iframe-returns-parent-as-undefined-using-wordpress), jQuery being run in noConflict mode, unbeknownst to the user. If this is the case for you, you'd have to modify your script to

```
parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
```

If none of those work, please use a tool like Firebug for Firefox, or the developer console for Chrome, to see if there is an error message, and report back to us what it is.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

**assuming that** `$.fancybox.close();` works in the parent window.

Comment: fancybox opens a DIV element, not an actual popup window, so there won't be a `window.opener`.

Comment: @David How can you post this comment when you, yourself used `window.parent` in your answer? You did something like that and still think fancybox opens a div and not another window(iframe) in this case?

Comment: It opens a div with an iframe. An iframe does not have a `window.opener`.

Comment: @David I tested and it seems it doesn't... I would have expected an iframe to act just like a popup. I'm sorry. I was surprised by the fact that you said it opens a DIV. I thought you were under the impression it always uses AJAX.

Comment: alright, I guess we misunderstood one another, all I meant to say was that `window.opener` won't work, as only popup windows have an opener. Anything else is not *opened* in the same sense. Whether or not it resembles a popup in the design is something the iframe isn't aware of. The problem with noConflict is that it's often used in places like WordPress, without the developer knowing it, and wrapped, so that the `$` can still be used; `(function($) { $.fancybox.close(); /* this will work */ })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#fancybox-close").trigger('click');
```

Comment: this helps out quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

When you're using fancybox with type: iframe, in the iframe box you have to insert all your libraries like jquery etc. Then to close iframe fancy box just use parent.$.fancybox.close()

Remember fancybox with type "iframe" opens in new window, fancybox with other types opens in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, this is the only solution i could finds that did the trick:

the code itself is:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

it runs in a function as such:

```
jQuery("#cancelId").click(function(){
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
});
```

hopes it helps,
Naore

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

does this work ?

Answer (score 0):

//on child window or iframe put this function:

`function closeIframe(){
        parent.closeIframeMain();
 }`

// and this link to close this window

`<a onclick="closeIframe();" href="#">Close window</a>`

//then on parent window put this function:

`function closeIframeMain(){
   jQuery("#fancybox-close").trigger("click");
}`

Answer (score 0):

It'll work for sure, just copy and paste it:

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="jQuery('.fancybox-close').fancybox().trigger('click');">Close from Inside</a>`

Actually it triggers close button if fancybox itself, which works in majority of cases.

Have fun with programming :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with ASP.NET.

Basically, on a page, I'm opening a page (with a form control inside) like this:

```
$.fancybox({
                href: '/ContactUs.aspx',
                type: 'iframe',
                padding: 60,
                width: 465,
                height: 670,
                maxWidth: 465,
                maxHeight: 670,
            });
```

When I click close on the FancyBox, it works, but if I submit it first THEN close it, the `fancyBox` won't close, even thou the page is in the same domain.

In the end, I found out you must set autoSize:false when you open the FancyBox:

```
 $.fancybox({
                href: '/ContactUs.aspx',
                type: 'iframe',
                padding: 60,
                width: 465,
                height: 670,
                maxWidth: 465,
                maxHeight: 670,
                autoSize: false
            });
```

It should now work. Please reply if this works for anyone else. Cheers.

Will

Answer (score -1):

parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
with .$. - creashes in IE8.
With this - all ok.

Comment: btw i add try() block and few notations of this (closing fancy), i find here. And it start working in IE/FF. :