# fancybox do not close from child

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fancybox

when I am trying to close fancybox from Ifarame child 
using JavaScript "parent.$.fancybox.close();"

in IE it is working 
but in chrome + Firefox doesn't working

also try the following command too

```
 "  parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            //$.fancybox.close()
            //window.close();
        //  parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
        //  window.parent.$.fancybox.close();"
```

and nothing works

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console of chrome/firefox?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390581/how-to-close-fancybox-from-child-window?rq=1

Comment: Is the iFrame in the exact same domain as the parent?

Comment: Kamlesh Kushwaha - I sue it before I postet my q

Comment: Ayman Safadi - yes it is in the same domain

Comment: It all depends on what context you are trying to run the close method. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987 if that helps (includes demo)