# Best Practice: using jQuery within an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

**CASE 1:** 
once when using fancybox, i was not able to get the following code to work within an iframe.(yes i tried all the flavours related to the following code. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227096/fancybox-iframe-returns-parent-as-undefined-using-wordpress/7278247#7278247) [i have also replied to this thread] )

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Finally I solved this problem by removing the main jquery file(jquery-1.5.2.min.js) from within the iframe.

**CASE 2:**
in another page of the same project, the same fancybox(iframe) was saying **$ is not defined**.

Now, I solved this problem by adding the main jquery file(jquery-1.5.2.min.js) inside the iframe.

**The problem i am facing now:** $.fancybox.resize wont work for this iframe!(i strongly believe its cuz of the main jquery(jquery-1.5.2.min.js) i am including inside the iframe.)

This is confusing to me. I searched for issues when using jquery in iframes. some say there is no problem having another jquery inside the iframe. most ppl dont seem to have problems? cuz i was not able to find many related questions.

1. Please tell me what is going wrong here. Something i need to take care of when using jquery within iframes?.
2. Also please refer me to some resources i need to be looking up to handle these kinds of problems. like related to iframes? or iframes and javascript, scope related problems? etc?

**Note:**
 1. these iframes are working correctly when individually accessed with a jquery-1.5.2.min.js included at the top.
 2. **My environment** : **windows xp | firefox 3.6.22 | jquery 1.5.2 | fancybox 1.3.4**

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought it might be a bug in jquery? After all, you are using an old version. Maybe you should download [Jquery 1.6.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/12/jquery-1-6-4-released/), try it, and post back here if you're still having problems.

Comment: Hello Mark.. I just tried using 1.6.4 but no luck! .  The scripts using $, are working in fancy box-iframe(without having the main jquery file within it)  for the same project, but in other pages. only difference is, that those pages had got ui tabs/ or uploadify in it. I was thinking if its something in those codes which is making the parent $ available within the iframes?