# Fancybox.close() on an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, dom, xhtml, fancybox

i am using the latest fancybox (2.0.4) and i created a fancybox for an iframe. the content is displayed correctly. i add a "close" button to my html which is displyed within the iframe. i wish that the close button will have the same result as clicking the "x" on the right top corner of the fancybox. i am familiar with [FancyBox iframe returns parent.$ as undefined (using WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227096/fancybox-iframe-returns-parent-as-undefined-using-wordpress), and my `parent` is a DOM object with nothing in it. also tried

```
window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
window.parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

any help?

UPDATE:

## a.js (linked to the a.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        type        : 'iframe',
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterClose  : function() { 
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

## a.html

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" id="newLink" href="new.html">link</a>
```

how can i have a button within `new.html` that closes the fancybox iframe window

UPDATE: a complete html files

## a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    maxWidth    : 800,
                    maxHeight   : 600,
                    fitToView   : false,
                    width       : '70%',
                    height      : '70%',
                    autoSize    : false,
                    closeClick  : false,
                    type        : 'iframe',
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    afterClose  : function() { 
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" id="newLink" href="b.html">link</a>


    </body>
</html>
```

## b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="cancelBtn" onclick="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 32):

Your manual close button should look like:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"><img src="myCloseButton.png" alt="close fancybox" /></a>
```

**UPDATE**: you should use the `onsubmit` on the `<form>` tag, not on the `button` image so in your "new.html" set something like

```
<form id="login_form" action="process.php" onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">
```

**UPDATE #2**: see [working demo page](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/openFormIframeandCloseOnsubmit_02feb12.html)

**UPDATE #3**: I have decided to remove all my additional comments to this answer since the discussion became too long and took us nowhere. I let the code and a link to a working demonstration if this can help somebody else though.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, though it is not working! `<body><form onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"><input type="submit" value="Cancel"/></form></body>` and that's what chrome's developer tools prints `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined`

Comment: firstly, thanks a lot. secondly, if that's not much to ask, could you please zip it and put a link for it. since i downloaded your files, changed the path to my fancybox directory and it is not working. (the iframe opens up, but the closing isn't working)

Comment: here is a link to my directory, which includes your files and the fancybox directory http://www.mediafire.com/?0u04zdrz6v2tdi8 -- how come it is not working?

Comment: i do not have a hosting which i can use.. at least not one that surves http

Comment: any chance you could put your demo in a zip?

Comment: i want a zip file to examine your directory structre and which files of fancybox you refer explicity in your code, and to verify if there is some dependency between fancybox's files. what it has to do with server? (even though i have one), it should not be a problem to simulate a webpage in offline; or am i mistaken?

Comment: library which cannot be used localy is not implemented correctly. too many threads all over the internet regarding fancybox. i guess it is better to use some better and clever implementations. thank you anyway.

Comment: it's not the library but mostly how differently browsers handle things ... you will learn that with the time (if you are serious about learning and understanding). For now, the easiest way is to blame fancybox

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue with a fancybox iframe popup. It works to add onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); to the form tag, and successfully closes the iframe popup, but this prevents the form from submitting. I am submitting my form to the wordpress admin.php file. I need to process the values in the form and then return back to the popup and close it. Any suggestions for this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

```
    try{
        parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }catch(err){
        parent.$('#fancybox-overlay').hide();
        parent.$('#fancybox-wrap').hide();
    }
```

!!!Not Support onClose!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Javascript:

$.fancybox.close();

Comment: Try including more details on where you would put the code in the JS

Comment: @Lima Please review the initial question again! The question does not provide too much Javascript either. There are no details for me to provide...

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$( '.fancybox-overlay', window.parent.document ).click();
```