# Close iframe fancybox when child page submitted and reload parent page

Tags: c#, jquery, fancybox

I have iframe fancybox on my page. On the child page, I add something to DB when Add Button clicked. After this process I want to close the fancybox and reload the parent page. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you  using jquery ajax for submit? then it is possible...

Comment: ajax for submit it is easy to do... k.. after submitting the page is loading that time dialog can close?

Answer (score 1):

this should be called on  page reload..

```
   window.parent.closeDialogFormSubmit();

   //Or

   window.top.parent.closeDialogFormSubmit();
```

this `closeDialogFormSubmit` function should be on fancy box open on that page.
   `closeDialogFormSubmit` write code for fancy box close code.

the function should be written outside `$(document).ready(function(){});` or      `$(function(){});` else it will not find the function and gives error undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**1). In the child page**

Use the API method `parent.$.fancybox.close()`

You could create a button like :

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"><img src="myCloseButton.png" alt="close fancybox" /></a>
```

**Bear in mind** that interaction between those pages is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) so if the child page is in another domain `parent.$.fancybox.close()` may not work.

**EDIT** : if the child page should be closed after a form is submitted, then set the closing method using the `onsubmit` attribute in the `form` tag like :

```
<form id="login_form" action="process.php" onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987) for further reference and demo.

**2). In the parent page**

Add to your custom script the `afterClose`  callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

... to reload the page after closing fancybox. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EWTxv/)**