# Fancybox closing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I used fancybox and it works in Mozilla but I'm getting `TypeError: parent.$ is undefined` in console but it working. In Chrome the error shows also in console. But the problem is I can used it only once. After closing it and tried one more time it failed in Chrome.

My fancybox open a page, that page is my adding record page. So when I finished to add records the fancybox should close itself. But when parent.$.fancybox.close(); is not in my codes the fancybox are not closing and it's just open another page inside of it.

If there any code for replacement in `parent.$.fancybox.close();` ?

My link open fancybox.

```
<td><a class="fancybox" href="add.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">ADD</a></td>
```

Fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        helpers   : {
  overlay : {
  closeClick: false}
  // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
  },
  closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox
  scrolling     : 'no',
  width            : 400,
  height           : 0,
  autoScale        : true,
  openEffect      : 'elastic',
  closeEffect     : 'fade',
  closeBtn : true,
  beforeShow: function(){
  $(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor","transparent");
  },
  afterClose:function () {
  window.location.reload();
  }
    }).trigger("onclick");
});
parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$.fancybox.close`? How does it fail? Could you [setup a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for troubleshooting.

Comment: @JSuar it's not working. My fancybox open a page, that page is my adding record page. So when I finished to add records the fancybox should close itself. But when parent.$.fancybox.close(); is not in my codes the fancybox are not closing and it's just open another page inside of it.

Comment: `parent.$.fancybox.close();` should be called from the page opened inside the fancybox iframe, not in the parent page. It works first time but the one on the parent page triggers a js error and prevents from working properly again

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987 for a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox.close() on an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117975/fancybox-close-on-an-iframe)

Comment: @JFK just like this in page in iframe? <script>
parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>

Comment: Check the link I posted, includes a demo. The method should be called when is needed, not just like that

Comment: You may also try `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()` to avoid possible conflicts

Comment: @JFK It works, but the problem in Chrome was not solve. Why I can used once? After that the fancybox is not open