# How to close a fancybox popup window immediately after submitting a form in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, popup, window, fancybox

I am developing a social network web site for time management using Symfony2. As an administrator of a group in that web site, you can add an event in the calendar of your group. The page is as below:
[image]

If you click anywhere on the calendar, a fancybox popup window will be displayed containing a form as you can see at the shot screen below:
[image]

What I would like to know is how can I make the fancybox popup window close immediately after submitting the form that it contains. This is the code of the page (that the fancybox popup window) which contains the form:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Wkayet </title>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/images/icon-WKAYET.png')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/css2/css.css')}}"/>
        <script src='{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/lib/jquery.min.js')}}'></script> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
              function mout() {

                  $(document).jQuery.fancybox.close();
              </script>
    <center>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {% for x in groupe%}
   <form id="EventForm" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
                                {% endfor %}
                                 {{ form_errors(form) }}
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="groupname">Titre</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                     <!--<input id="titre" name="titre" required="required" type="text" size="50"/> -->
                                         <div>
                                            {{ form_errors(form.title) }}

                                            {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
                                           </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="debut">Début</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="debut" name="debut" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.start ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.start ) }}
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="fin">Fin</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="fin" name="fin" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.end ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.end ) }}
                                          </div> 

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="lieu">Lieu</label></td>
                                        <td> <!--<select id="lieu" name="lieu" class="select"></select> -->

                                         <div>
                                           {{ form_errors(form.location) }}

                                         {{ form_widget(form.location , {'attr':{'class':'select '}}) }}
                                          </div>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="description" valign="top" class="separation"><label for="description">Description</label></td>
                                        <td><textarea id="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe_description" name="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe[description]" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> 



                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" id="button" valign="bottom"><input class="button" type="submit" value="" onclick="mout()"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                         {{form_widget(form._token)}} 
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

As you notice, I put the instruction `$(document).jQuery.fancybox.close();` .. what is the right instruction to put here??...Is there anyone who has any idea?

Comment: `$(document).jQuery.fancybox.close();` is wrong, it should be `jQuery.fancybox.close();` (`$` is an alias of `jQuery`). Bind a `submit` event (instead of `click`) to the `form` element and call the closing method from there

Comment: or you could do something like `<form id="myform" onsubmit="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();" action="{whatever}">`

Comment: this is an example when the form is inside an iframe http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987 but if the form is inline then you don't need to set `parent`

Comment: first there is a typo in mout function, and to hide the fancybox in the parent document use `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();`

Comment: @JFK: how can I put : onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" inside a javascript function??..I tried $(document).parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); but it didn't work..do you have any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your funciton should be

```
<script>
function mout() {
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
};
</script>
```

then call it `onsubmit` like

```
<form id="EventForm" onsubmit="mout()" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/th6hqksu/)** (use *persist* in your console)

For more information about fancybox close methods, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987