# Why is the fancybox close function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox v-2.1.5. I am trying to close the fancyox by clicking on button. I have tried several times in several ways, but nothing happen, even no error in console.

What I have tried by using following code under custom button in click event:

```
1. $.fancybox.close();
2. $.fn.fancybox.close();
3. $.fancybox.close(true); 
4. $(".fancybox-close").trigger('click');
5. $('.fancybox-overlay').css('display','none');
```

What is the perfect way to close the fancybox under custom button?

Comment: `$.fancybox.close()` should work

Comment: Try `<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">close</a>` notice `parent` is used to close fancybox from an iframe. You can omit it if closing from an inline content. see more http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118087/1055987

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="parent.window.document.getElementById('fancybox-wrap').style.display = 'none';">Close</a>
```

Comment: Ordinarily it's good to offer a little explanation along with your code in an answer.