# parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); from within Fancybox only closes Fancybox once

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to close a Fancybox instance from a link within the Fancybox content. I'm using `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();` as recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227096/fancybox-iframe-returns-parent-as-undefined-using-wordpress). It works the first time, but thereafter not. Can anyone suggest a fix?

I'm hiding my content div in the page with this:

```
#content {
    display: none;
}
```

And here's the link launching the Fancybox, with that content div, which includes the link to close the Fancybox.

```
<a href="#" id="launch">Launch</a>

<div id="content">
    <p>Nunc porttitor pellentesque magna a pulvinar. Vestibulum id diam lectus. Praesent vel dictum est.</p>

    <a href="#" id="close">Close</a>
</div>
```

And this is my JS. I've tried adding the event hander to the close link on opening the Fancybox, but it didn't help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#launch').fancybox({
        'width': 300,
        'content': $('#content'),
        'onClosed':function () {
            $("#content").hide();
        },
        'onStart':function () {
            $("#content").show();
            $('#close').on('click', function(){
                //console.log($(this).parent);
                parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
            })
        },
        'onCleanup':function () {
            $("#content").unwrap();
        }
    });
})
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: So what happens if you just put the `$('#close').on()` function _outside_ of the `.fancybox()` function?

Comment: Same thing Sparky - the lightbox closes the first time you launch it, but not after that.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.   I use fancyBox and never had any problems like yours. According to [the fancyBox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs), I can't even find the `onClosed`, `onStart` or `onCleanup` methods.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, maybe I'm using a different version - I'll investigate. So you can close Fancyboxes programmatically?

Comment: As simple as `$.fancybox.close();`

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try that with the version you've given me the link to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();` should be called from within an `iframe` opened in fancybox. In your case you are opening `inline` content so the prefix `parent` is not needed. Additionally you must provide the correct structure to your inline content and call the closing function from there.

So your inline content should look like

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="content">
   <p>Nunc porttitor pellentesque magna a pulvinar. Vestibulum id diam lectus. Praesent vel dictum est.</p>
   <a href="javascript:;" id="close">Close</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

because of the above you don't need this css

```
#content {
    display: none;
}
```

since `#content` is already inside a hidden `div`.

then your closing function can be separated from the fancybox script... also notice the changes on the fancybox script below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#close').on('click', function(){
  //console.log($(this).parent);
  $.fancybox.close();
 }); //on
/*
// you could also do 
$('#close').click(function(){
 $.fancybox.close();
});
*/
 $('#launch').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
   'width': 300,
   'href': '#content',
   'onCleanup':function () {
    $("#content").unwrap();
   }
  });//fancybox
 }); // click
}); //ready
```

this is for Fancybox v1.3.x, the version you seem to be using. Also you should be using jQuery v1.7.x if you want the `.on()` method to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{
        parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }catch(err){
        parent.$('#fancybox-overlay').hide();
        parent.$('#fancybox-wrap').hide();
    }
```

!!!Not Support onClose!!!