# Submit Form And Close Fancybox, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fancybox, submit

I'm using Fancybox to trigger a search form pop-up and the form uses Javascript validation to check and submit. The problem that I have is that I can't get the Fancybox screen to close and then run the function. Here is the code that I'm using at the moment:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $search; ?>.php?type=rad" onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">

$('#enterButton').click(function()
        {
        if(searchok == 1)
        {           
            $('.searchValidation').addClass("sending");
            $("#searchForm").submit();
        }
        else
        {
        $('.searchValidation').addClass("validationError");
        }
        return false;
        });
```

How can I get the fancybox window to close on submit() but still effectively run the form function in the parent window?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `#enterButton` is the `submit` button, you are better off calling the

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

inside the validation function. I'd suggest something like this:

```
$('#enterButton').click(function()
        {
        if(searchok == 1)
        {           
            $('.searchValidation').addClass("sending");
            $("#searchForm").submit();
            parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
        }
        else
        {
        $('.searchValidation').addClass("validationError");
        }
        return false;
        });
```

However `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();` needs to be used only if you are using it within an `iframe`. You can replace it with `jQuery.fancybox.close();`

Here's a reference you can check: [parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); from within Fancybox only closes Fancybox once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725023/parent-jquery-fancybox-close-from-within-fancybox-only-closes-fancybox-once)

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. The solution came from simply using _parent as the target for the form: `<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $search; ?>.php?type=name" target="_parent">`